# Can't change a custom font in third party library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, splash-screen

I'm new to third party libraries, I'm using a splash screen as a start activity to my project. [AwsomeSplashScreen](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash)

there's attribute called titleFont which takes String! , i can't change to any font. already tried so many ways but the problem that it takes only String and the font i use will only be Int or Typeface (converting it to String doesn't solve the problem). It says a problem with the assets folder.

Note that the library is old and font is now in resources file not assets folder, already tried to make assets directory with fonts in it but the issue.

Edit: I've tried another third party library [Splashy](https://github.com/rahuldange09/Splashy)

I found 2 dependencies in Android Arsenal, The first one is

`implementation 'com.github.rahuldange09:Splashy:v1.1.0'`
which works fine but doesn't have any functions to change fonts.

The second one is
`implementation 'com.rbddevs.splashy:splashy:1.3.0'`
which is not working at all and even Splashy class is not implemented.
So can you help me with that please.

Comment: You should probably better try to ask the contributors of the lib.

Comment: unfortunately he doesn't respond that's why I wanted some help in here instead. @Brian

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how SO nor open source works ;-) Just fork, adjust to your needs, and use.